# Append data to a file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

See a piece of code below. I get a number of files, how can I merge them all into one file? Actually, the Append mode does not work, because it creates several files. I expected one file.

```
val schema = new StructType()
        .add(StructField("title", StringType, true))
      spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD = newsInTrend, schema = schema)
        .coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json("D:/data/spark/file.txt")
```

**UPDATE**
We need to load the partitioned stored files, and then save it as one whole file.
Code changes are below. @Nikk Thank you.

```
val schema = new StructType()
        .add(StructField("title", StringType, true))
      spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD = newsInTrend, schema = schema)
        .coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode(SaveMode.Append).save("D:/data/spark")//.show(20, false)
val df1 = spark.read.format("json").load("D:/data/spark")
df1.coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("D:/data/spark/subdir")
```

Comment: If you want to write into one file `coalesce(1)` should do the trick. save mode `append` doesn't work like that.

Comment: @blackbishop I used `coalesce(1)` but there are many files yet

Comment: @alexander.sivak, it is not possible you can only write one batch file into one but it is not possible to append multiple batch data into one single file. There is one solution  that you can do is, after append data/file , read all these data back into dataframe and write it at another path using coalesce (1) with overwrite.

Comment: @Nikk how do you read it back into DataFrame if file names are created based on some algorithm?

Comment: @alexander.sivak, i dont know it will be feasible for you or not. Generally I am not recommending. Once you write data as df.write.format("xyz").mode("append").save("path1"), create new dataframe with same path like val df1 = spark.read.format("xyz").load("/path1") and write it back to new path as   df1.coalesce(1).write.format("xyz").mode("overwrite").save("path2", give path of parent directory not any file name.